Stata: Number of overlapping dates in date range (non-unique values)
This question is based on a previous answer Stata: Number of overlapping days within multiple date ranges that has (mostly) helped me. I want to calculate the number of overlapping days within multiple date ranges - I need the full list of dates in a range to be listed out (i.e., reshape data from wide to long).
A solution was posted. However, I get an error because my dates are not unique (As in the fake data below):
/* Fake Data */
input str9(start  end)      
"01jan2000" "04apr2000"
"30may2000" "15aug2000"
"07jan2000" "31dec2000"
end

foreach var of varlist start end {
    gen d = date(`var', "DMY")
    drop `var'
    gen `var' = d
    format %td `var'
    drop d
}

/* Count Overlapping Days */
rename (start end) date=
gen spell = _n
reshape long date, i(spell) j(range) string
drop range
xtset spell date, delta(1 day)
tsfill
bys date: keep if _N>1

Can anyone help me adjust this code to allow for non-distinct dates?

I don't understand what non-unique or non-distinct dates means here. Your 6 dates in the fake data are all distinct.

I don't understand what bearing the code you cite has on determining overlaps in time between the individuals implied by each observation. With many guesses on what you want, this produces a dataset that allows counting of overlaps.
clear 

/* Fake Data */
input str9(start  end)      
"01jan2000" "04apr2000"
"30may2000" "15aug2000"
"07jan2000" "31dec2000"
end

gen id = _n 
rename (start end) (str_date1 str_date2) 

reshape long str_date, i(id) j(which)
gen date = daily(str_date, "DMY")

tsset id date 
tsfill 

bysort date : gen n = _N 

spikeplot date, yla(0/2) base(0)

